# Square root "base"

Tags: number-theory, cryptography, integer-lattices

In normal base system (say binary), you'll do `P = [1,2,4,8, ...]` then a value can be represented as coefficients $\{a_i\}$ where $$N=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\cdot P_i$$

However, I am given a problem where

- The base is $P=\{\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\cdots, \sqrt{101}, \sqrt{103}\}$.
- The value $N<12000$ rounded to $2^{-256}$
- $a_i < 128,\forall a_i$
- $n=27$, meaning it only uses the first $27$ primes.

I am to recover the coefficients $a$.

---

Can someone give some insights to how this can be approached? An idea I have right now is that I can multiply by say $2^{256}$ and work with integers, then I have to find an array of $a=\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{27}\}$ with every element below 128 that "approximately" makes $n$. I also notice that since $N<12000$ and $\sum P\approx 170.48$, there is a bound 21821 which is pretty close..? Another way might be to use some property about gaps between $P_i$ and $P_{i+1}$?

I think it is similar to the [Merkle-Hellman knapsack cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Hellman_knapsack_cryptosystem) which can be cracked with lattice reduction, but it is not super-increasing here and I can't seem to find a way to make it so.

I can also model it as a knapsack problem but it either explodes in time complexity (IIRC most algorithms depend on $V$ which is large when you convert to integers) or is approximate and might not find the solution.

Hope someone can provide some insights~

Thank you!
Gareth